# Bower-rails ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, bower

I'm using [bower-rails](https://github.com/rharriso/bower-rails) to manage assets. This is a very weird error I got when I try to use [simplemde](https://github.com/NextStepWebs/simplemde-markdown-editor). I installed simplemde using Bowerfile

```
asset "bootstrap", "4.0.0-alpha.6"
asset "jquery"
asset "backbone", "1.1.1"
asset "simplemde"
```

This is how I include the library in my `application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require simplemde
//= require_tree .
```

The error in my browser console doesn't say much:

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined
TypeError: this.render is not a function
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?